# vSphere 5.1 Web Client: cannot edit vSwitch settings on one host

Tags: vmware-vsphere

One host in my two-host cluster shows "Edit Settings (Unavailable)" when hovering over the grayed-out pencil icons.

Second host is fine.

No idea, Google wisdom eludes me.

EDIT:

- logged in as root (local authentication)
- client, Windows 7 64-bit, latest Flash, IE10, Chrome and Firefox latest versions.
- Have not modified any permissions; created two hosts, setup basic networking for Management Network.
- No issues modifying vSwitch via Windows client either directly to the host or vCenter.

Screenshot here:
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounced offending host, worked.

Comment: Ran into the same weird problem on ESXi 5.5, tried restarting the services on the ESX (/sbin/services.sh restart) but no joy. Had to reboot and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try making the change using the Windows client or even going to the host directly? Also check the "Work in Progress" list on the right pane of the GUI just to make sure there isn't another editing session.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, only reason I'm in Web Client as I'm trying to configure vSphere Replication and the checkbox to enable replication on the VMKernel is not present through the Windows client.

Comment: Work in Progress is empty too.

Comment: Might bounce vCenter Appliance.  Nothing's in production.

Comment: bouncey no workie.  Added screenshot.  Will try blowing away browser cache.

Comment: Blew away cache, tried 3 browsers now.  No dice.